# Static variables, threads and constructor Java

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, static

I have seen this from a recognised sample book so its hard to question then there is something I dont understand.

> A class called DataflightsService contains a private static variable called FlightFileAccess that appears to be instantiated everytime we create a new object for DataflightsService as  FlightFileAccess's initiation its in  the constructor

ie

```
public class DataflightsService{
    private static FlightFileAccess fileAccess=null;

    public DataflightsService(String path){
         fileAccess=new flightFileAccess(path);
    }

    public boolean removeflight(String code){
         //We use this static instance that wraps functionality to remove a flight
         fileAccess.remove(code);
    }
}
```

---

For me that means that every time we create an instance of `DataflightsService`, in the constructor are using a different object all the time for the static variable `FlightFileAccess`

> In the original `FlightFileAccess` Class: we have the remove method that synchronizes a `RandomAccessFile`

```
Class FlightFileAccess{
    private RandomAccessFile database = null;
    private boolean remove(String code){
        // Other code goes here and there

        synchronized (database) {
             //Perform deletion code
        }
    }
```

So because we are using a different reference of `FlightFileAccess` we are also using a different reference of `RandomAccessFile`?

That means that having `FlightFileAccess` as static in service does not serve here to `synchronize` on the `RandomAccessFile` because it is a new one every time so each `DataflightsService` instance will do their thing on the random access file ignoring the synchronization.
As opposed to instantiating `FlightFileAccess` in a static initiator. Am I right?

I would appreciate as many explanations as possible to provide the best way to be able to instantiate `DataflightsService` as many times as we want (as lets say  imagining each client has their own instance of `DataflightsService`) and after that being able to synchronize on a file for removals for example so that there is no mess of several clients accessing the file. Sorry I need to include a `DataflightsService` per client bc there are no cookies.

Comment: Please edit your question and format the code as code, and indent it.

Comment: Just because you find advice in a book, that doesn't automatically make it _good_ advice.  The constructor unconditionally assigns a static field?  That sounds like seriously bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Your example won't compile because the name of the constructor doesn't match the class.  But if you mean to name the constructor `public DataflightsService()`, then part  of the issue is that you are overwriting the static variable each time a new object is created.

It sounds like you want this static variable to be initialized only once. Normally you would just assign the variable directly with `private static final FlightFileAccess fileAccess = new FlightFileAccess();` or if you wanted to add more logic as if you had a constructor, you could use a static initializer block as follows:

```
public class Dataflights {

    private static final FlightFileAccess fileAccess;

    static {
      // Static initializer block gets run once when the class is first referenced.
      // Not usually used unless you want to add more logic besides just initializing variables.
      fileAccess = new FlightFileAccess();
    }

    private final String path;
    public final int id;

    public Dataflights(String path) {
      this.path = path;
      this.id = fileAccess.generateId();
    }

  static class FlightFileAccess {

    private volatile int nextId = 0;
    synchronized public int generateId() {
      return nextId++;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dataflights d = new Dataflights("my/path");
    System.out.println("Id is: " + d.id);
  }
}
```

There are many ways to handle contention. I recommend [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) if you aren't familiar with Java concurrency.

You are on the right track in your FlightFileAccess class.   I can't see the details, but you might also want to use the `synchronized` keyword in the signature of the `remove()` method to protect the entire function first.  Then, once you have things working, use more tightly targeted `synchronize {...}` blocks to reduce the amount of code that has to be singly threaded.

Comment: Thanks eric, that was a typo so I fixed it, yes, basically I wanted to know if my thinking is correct, as we need to use the same object to apply synchronisation on threads, and in the example I provide, it instantiates the static object in the constructor, so it appears its wrong to me, I think its much better to instantiate before the constructor.Thanks for the book recommendation too, I heard about it many times so yes I will have to start reading it to understand all the multiple possibilities

Comment: That is not a static constructor. It's an instance initializer block. And it will have the same problem as a constructor. BTW, this would not compile since the field is final. If what you meant is a *static initializer block*, then the syntax is `static { ... }`. But it's not needed. You can simply initialize the static variable directly, as part of its declaration.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, I cleaned up the terminology and the code in the example.